# Syntax and Variable Declaration in Nested Loops: How Does an Inner Declaration take Precedence?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, operator-precedence, variable-declaration

I was following an example of how to produce a script in java that computes and prints the powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16...) and the script looks like this:

```
class Power {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

     int e;
     int result;

     for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     result = 1; //why doesn't this reset result to 1 for every iteration?
     e = i;
        while(e > 0) {
        result *= 2;
        e --;
        }

        System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
        //I would expect printing "result" here would result in 2 every time...
     }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
2 to the 1 power is 2
2 to the 2 power is 4
2 to the 3 power is 8
2 to the 4 power is 16
2 to the 5 power is 32
2 to the 6 power is 64
2 to the 7 power is 128
2 to the 8 power is 256
2 to the 9 power is 512
```

My question is that if the **result** variable is declared as 1 within the initial **for** loop but outside the inner **while** loop, how come its value doesn't reset to 1 every time the **for** loop runs? It's clear to me that the **for** loop begins running before the **while** loop takes over, because the **System.out.println()** command is run every time. What is it about Java's structure that allows this?

Comment: Variables are created when first declared within a block, and thrown away when the block exits.  In your example, `result` belongs to the block asociated with the execution of `main()` - so it is created on the line when it is declared, and thrown away when main() exits.  But - every time through the loop, that existing variable _is_ set to 1 by the application: it is where the power of 2 is accumulated for each value of i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely right about `result` being reset to 1 in each iteration of the for loop. It does get reset.

"But why doesn't printing `result` give me 2 every time" you ask.

After `result` is being set to 1, and before that iteration of the for loop ends, the while loop runs. How many times does the while loop runs? It depends on `i`. In the first iteration of the for loop, the while loop loops once, in the second iteration of the for loop, the while loop loops twice, in the third iteration of the for loop, the while loop loops three times, and so on.

At the end of each iteration of the for loop, `result` will contain the value of 2 to the power `<however many times the while loop looped for>`. So at the end of the first iteration of the for loop, `result` is 2 because the while loop looped only once. At the end of the second iteration, `result` is 4 because the while loop ran twice and so `result *= 2` is ran twice.

If `result` isn't reset, it would have become 8 by the end of the second iteration of the for loop: it got multiplied once in the first iteration, and twice in the second iteration.

Comment: Thanks! Makes total sense. It seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 0):

please check below inline explanations

```
class Power {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

     int e;
     int result;

     for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     result = 1; //why doesn't this reset result to 1 for every iteration?
                // Yes , result will be 1 always here, you can print the result variable before while as below
     // System.out.println("Result : " + result);
     e = i;
        while(e > 0) {
        result *= 2;
        e --;
        }

        System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
        //I would expect printing "result" here would result in 2 every time...
        // here the value of result will be decided based on e, here we are multiplying result with 2 , "e" no.of times
     }
    }
}
```